# 301 Redirection To All Pages

Tags: .htaccess

i want to do 301 redirection with the search query.

for example: abc.com should redirect to abc.org
and if someone suppose to enter abc.com/xyz.html then it must also redirect to abc.org/xyz.html

below is the current htaccess part.

```
RewriteRule pages/(.*) single.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rss.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*)\.html song.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current rules seem to be faulty since `RewriteCond` only applies to very next `RewriteRule`. With the new rule have your complete .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ single.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^rss\.xml$ rss.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ song.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the directory structure stayed the same between domains, you can do this via the following:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If the directory structure DID change, you can use additional rules on the NEW domain's `.htaccess` file to map appropriately.